# Sorting WPF datagrid with ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I have filled a WPF DataGrid by setting the ItemSource with the desired table (DataTable). Now I do want to sort the table by a value in one of the DataTable column. I do not want to sort the table using the default sorting which can be used by clicking on the table headers. I do want want sort the table using a ComboBox. You can select one of the items in the combobox and the table will sort. I have implemented the code below. However when I change the selected item in the combobox, the DataGrid will be empty. All records are not shown. The headers are still visible.

```
        private void DbFilterSortByBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DbFilterSortByBox.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                DbMainTable.ItemsSource = SortedTable(DbFilterSortByBox.SelectedItem.ToString()).DefaultView;

                for (int i = 0; i < propertiesHandler.TablePropertiesIndex.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (propertiesHandler.TablePropertiesValue[i] == false)
                    {
                        DbMainTable.Columns[propertiesHandler.TablePropertiesIndex[i]].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private DataTable SortedTable(string sortingBy)
        {
            DataView sortedTable = dataHandler.KicksTable.Clone().DefaultView;

            if (sortingBy == "Type")
            {
                sortedTable.Sort = "Type";
            } else if (sortingBy == "Size, ascending")
            {
                sortedTable.Sort = "Size asc";
            }

            return sortedTable.ToTable();
        }
```

The `DbFilterSortByBox_SelectionChanged` event occurs when the selected item in the ComboBox is changed. The `SortedTable` function is then called to sort the table by the desired value.

Does someone see where it goes wrong and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you hide all your columns? Why is sorting hiding columns anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

If the itemssource is set to

```
  dataHandler.KicksTable.DefaultView = dataHandler.KicksTable.DefaultView;
```

You can just do:

```
  dataHandler.KicksTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Size asc"; 
  dataHandler.KicksTable.DefaultView.Refresh();
```

No cloning.

Obviously, you still need the logic chooses which sort string to set.

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable.Clone` creates a new `DataTable` with the same *structure* as the original `DataTable`, **but does not copy any *data*** (the new `DataTable` will not contain any `DataRows` - it will always be empty).
To copy both the structure and data into a new `DataTable`, use must `DataTable.Copy`.
However, you shouldn't clone nor copy the `DataTable` at all. It just creates unnecessary overhead.

Simply bind the `DataTable` to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource`. Because the `ItemsControl` in general works on collection views, all you need to do is to sort/filter/group the view. You don't have to refresh anything or reset the `ItemsSource` property.
Because collection view and collection are different layers, modifying the collection view does not modify the underlying collection (or `DataTable`). You therefore shouldn't clone/copy your `DataTable` before or after sorting/filtering/grouping it.

```cs
public Constructor()
{
  InitializeComponent();
 
  // Prefer data binding instead by simply binding to the DataTable.
  // Binding will automatically get the default view of the DataTable.
  DbMainTable.ItemsSource = dataHandler.KicksTable.DefaultView;
}

private void DbFilterSortByBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
  if (comboBox.SelectedItem is null)
  {
    return;
  }

  DataView kicksTableView = dataHandler.KicksTable.DefaultView;
  var sortConstraint = comboBox.SelectedItem as string;
  SortTable(kicksTableView, sortConstraint);
}

private void SortTable(DataView tableView, string sortConstraint)
{
  if (sortConstraint.Equals("Type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  {
    // Setting the Sort property will automatically sort the view and the DataGrid that binds to this view.
    tableView.Sort = "Type";
  }
  else if (sortConstraint.Equals("Size, ascending", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  {
    // Setting the Sort property will automatically sort the view and the DataGrid that binds to this view.
    tableView.Sort = "Size asc";
  }
}
```